# PIL import png pixels as single value instead of 3 values vector

Tags: python, image, png, python-imaging-library

I have a bunch of map files I've downloaded from Google maps in png formats that I want to convert to a single larger image. When I import one and I look at the pixels, I see that the pixels are a single number in the range of 0..256 instead of three values list. What's going on here?

I'm using

```
from PIL import Image

print open('b1.png').load()[0,0]
```

and I get `153` instead of [r,g,b]

my image file is [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason of such result (value 153 in `[0,0]`) is that image mode is set to `P` (8-bit pixels, mapped to any other mode using a colour palette). If You want to set different mode (e.g. `RGB`) You can do it before invoking method `load()`.

Here is an example of how to do this:

```
from PIL import Image
file_data = Image.open('b1.png')
file_data = file_data.convert('RGB') # conversion to RGB
data = file_data.load()
print data[0,0]
```

and the result of print is

```
(240, 237, 229)
```

For more information about Image Modes please visit [the documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes).

Comment: Thanks. Can I read the png file directly in ``RGB`` mode without using ``file_data = Image.open('b1.png').convert('RGB')``?

Comment: Hello, I don't know if it is possible and if a default mode can be set for all images. In this case this .png image has Colour Space set as Indexed Colour and that's why its loaded in P mode and needs to converted to RGB mode to obtain (r,g,b) tuple.

Answer (score 2):

Your image is in `mode=P`. It has it's colors defined in a color palette.

```
>>> Image.open('b1.png')
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=P size=640x640 at 0x101856B48>
```

You want a RGB value. First convert to RGB:

```
>>> im = Image.open('b1.png')
>>> im = im.convert('RGB')
>>> im.getpixel((1,1))
(240, 237, 229)
```

From the docs: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/concepts.html?highlight=mode

> P (8-bit pixels, mapped to any other mode using a color palette)
>   ...
>    RGB (3x8-bit pixels, true color)