# Reading PNG with PIL in Python

Tags: python, png, jpeg, python-imaging-library

I am reading a PNG file in Python. I want the RGB values for each pixel in the image:

```
  img = Image.open(path)
  pixels = img.load()
```

For a JPEG file the pixels are a **tuple** but for PNGs I am getting a single **integer**. How should I read PNG images with Python to get the pixel values?

Comment: Strange, I get a tuple when I open pngs on my machine. Have you tried this on more than one png?

Comment: Check your PNG file. If it is actually a grayscale or indexed color image - and *not* 24-bit color - your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/27093835/2564301

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like the image is being opened in grayscale mode. Try converting to RGB before accessing the pixel values.

```
img = Image.open(path).convert("RGB")
pixels = img.load()
```